# different files size c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, text-files

I am using visual studio 2012, when I compile the following code on a small text file (1500 words) it gives me the results I am expecting. However, when I compile it on a bigger file (75000 words), it doesn't give any error at all, but it acts as if it is copying the data from one file (input file) to the another file (output fie). All I am achanging is the name of the input file. One works fine and the other doesn't.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int occ = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int loc [30];
    int flag [30];
    ofstream output ("edit_2.txt");
    string word;
    ifstream input ("traindata/quran.txt");
    ifstream input2("diacritics.txt");
    char diac[11];
    string diacritic;
    while (input2>>diac[count])
    {
       diacritic=diac[count];
       count++;
    }
   while (input>>word)
    {
       occ=0;
       for (int j=0;j<30;j++)
        {
            loc[j]=0;
            flag[j]=0;
        }
        int size=word.length();
        for (int i=1;i<=size;i++)
        {
            if(i > 1)
            {
                if(word[i]==diac[0] && word[i+1]==diac[1])
                {
                loc[occ]=i;
                flag[occ] = 1;
                occ++;
                }
                else if(word[i]==diac[0] && word[i+1]==diac[2])
                {
                loc[occ]=i;
                flag[occ] = 2;
                occ++;
                }
                else if(word[i]==diac[0] && word[i+1]==diac[3])
                {
                loc[occ]=i;
                flag[occ] = 3;
                occ++;
                }

            }
        }

        for (int i=size;i>=0;i--)
        {
        if (loc[i]!=0 && flag [i]==1)
        {
        word.erase(loc[i],2);
                    word.insert(loc[i],"،");
        }
        else if (loc[i]!=0 && flag [i]==2)
        {
        word.erase(loc[i],2);
        word.insert(loc[i],".");
        }
        else if (loc[i]!=0 && flag [i]==3)
        {
        word.erase(loc[i],2);
        word.insert(loc[i],"~");
        }
        }
    output<<word<<" ";  
    }

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of potential out-of-bounds array accesses here; what if the word is longer than 30 characters? What if there's more than 11 characters in diacritics.txt? You also access `word[i]` and `word[i + 1]` even if `i` is equal to the word's length (or one less), which is incorrect. And you don't seem to look at the first two characters of any word at all. Actually, all your indexing into `word` seems to be off-by-one.

Comment: I am sure there is no word greater than 30 characters, and my diacritics file has only 11 characters. I am ignoring the first two characters, but I will check with word[i+1]. Still how it is working on one file and not the other?

Comment: Try stepping through the code with a debugger until you see where it's going wrong. It's entirely possible for buggy code to work in one context and not another; this can be caused by many things, e.g. out of bounds accesses overwriting other variable values with incorrect values in one run but accidentally correct values in another. In general, with C++ undefined behaviour, anything can happen, and often does because there's a lot less error-checking present than in other environments (so it's more up to the programmer and not the tool to validate their code).

Comment: You won't believe this!!! I just copied the data to another file, and I set that file to be the input file and it worked fine!!! I only copied the data from one text file to the other!!!

Comment: With these types of bugs it's often the location in memory of certain variables, or even the default values of certain variables, that change the behaviour of the program. Meaning it can potentially give a different result *every time you run it*, even with the same input. The other common error that I've seen is accidentally using an old binary after changing the source code (or having two versions of the source and changing one while recompiling the other thinking it's the changed one...). But I don't think that's the case here.